# changing control variable in Case statement in VHDL

Tags: switch-statement, vhdl

```
    case task is

       when 1 => task <= 2;

       when 2 => task <= 3; 

       when other =>...

    end case
```

I try to change the switch variable inside the case but it does not effect the value after case clause is passed. What is the proper way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use a signal assignment `<=` I assume that `task` is a signal, not a variable. The new value of task will be available in the next simulation cycle (delta cycle). This usually means that the new value will be visible when the process is executed again, or after a  "wait" statement (but you probably don't want wait statements if you are going to synthesize the code).

As an alternative, you can use a *variable* for `task`, and use the variable assignment operator: `task := 2;`

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable, not a signal - this will update the way you expect.

Signals are useful for communication between multiple processes, as their [updates are well-controlled](http://www.sigasi.com/content/vhdls-crown-jewel).  Ordinary variables are not and are therefore limited to process-scope, so can't be inadvertently used for inter-process communication which would then be error-prone.